# Using https just in a specific page - nginx

Tags: nginx, https

I am using NGINX as a web server. I would like to use **https** just in my **login** page, all other pages should serve http connection. How is possible to redirect the user to https when he types "/login" url prefix and then redirect to "http" when he types any other url suffix?

Thanks

Comment: Are you certain you only want to encrypt the login?  The session cookie being sent with non-encrypted requests will be [easily grabbed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep); if the session is sensitive, encrypt everything.

Comment: Hello Shane. Yes, I just would like that the password wont be sniffed. I don't have any other sensitive information.

Comment: Right, but is it a problem if someone is able to get logged into the application as if they had entered the password, without entering a password at all?

Comment: Hello Shane, yes user should just use the login/password in a https. In this moment I am not worrying about cookies or session that can be sniffed. So the idea i just to have https on /login url and than force http to any other url

Answer (score 1):

for example, like this

```
server {
    listen *:80;

    ...

    location /login {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }

    ...
}

server {
    listen *:443;
    ...
    location /login {
        # usual settings, proxy_pass etc...
    }

    location / {
        return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Cadmi, and how is possible to return to "http" when the user visits any other page?

Comment: what a stupid question? `listen *:80` will be http return on all pages, but `/login` (which forced redirect to https).

do you want force redirect from https:// site (listen *:443) to http (listen *:80) for all pages, but `/login`?

Comment: Yes Cadmi. After login I would like to redirect to http. Is it possible?

Comment: @Thomas, see update of my answer, redirect in `listen *:443` section